# How to renew Azure API management certificate

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

The certificate that came configured with our Azure API management endpoint expired today (apparently it was only valid for one year). How do we renew it?

We thought that the point of using the default API management certificate provided by MS meant we did not have to manually worry about renewing it. But this appears not to be the case.
[expired certificate message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgQXV.png)

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a Microsoft/Azure issue, as Azure manages this certificate. I would recommend creating a ticket in the Azure portal to report it.

Comment: This was an issue with the consumption sku and apim team fixed it.