# How to manage Azure App Service Certificate

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault

I have purchased an app service wildcard certificate and would like to import this cert into Azure Key vault for other purposes.  Once I export/import the cert into Azure key vault and use for other custom domains (for example: APIM) will the auto renew ability continue to work as expected (automatically) or will I be forced to manage the cert differently now stored in key vault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key Vault Certificates support automatic renewal with selected issuers - Key Vault partner X509 certificate providers / certificate authorities.

> Non-partnered providers/authorities are also allowed but, will not support the auto renewal feature.

So, the cert imported into key vault will [auto renew the cert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/about-keys-secrets-and-certificates#key-vault-certificates) instead of manually renewing it.

Answer (score 0):

The renewal process of the certificate is managed on key vault, so doesn't matter where you use it, it will be the same renewal process.

Comment: Just to confirm.  So a cert purchase within the Azure portal for an app service that is later exported to key vault for creating a custom domain with in APIM will auto renew automatically when the app service cert auto renews?

Comment: It will auto renew unless you require the opposite, that's the point of certificates managed by Azure, as stated in this thread as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701095/how-to-renew-azure-api-management-certificate